# Create empty multiple files in Unix that contain 0 bytes using awk or bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I am trying to create multiple empty files on Unix but I do not know if AWK command can do that or do I have to do it in bash? if yes could you help me, please?

At this moment I use this command:

```
seq 2 | awk '{print "" > "empty"i++".txt"}' i=1
```

however every file that is created is 1 byte. Is there a way to create 0 byte file using awk or bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do it in `awk`:

```
seq 2 | awk '{system(">" "empty" FNR ".txt")}'
```

That's not very clever though because it creates a whole new process for every line that `awk` reads.

@EdMorton's suggestion is therefore preferable, as he uses `awk`'s internal `printf` rather than creating a separate process:

```
seq 2 | awk '{printf "" > "empty" NR ".txt"}'
```

You would be better to use this:

```
touch {1..2}.txt
```

which only creates one process. However, that will not reduce to zero the size of any pre-existing files you may have - I don't generally like to assume folk are happy to lose data unless they explicitly say so in their question.

Comment: The `touch {1..2}.txt` is IMO the best answer so far!  One process and it achieves the ultimate goal of zero byte size files in the convention asked for. +1

Comment: You could also try: `seq 2 | awk '{printf "" > "empty"NR".txt"}'`.

Comment: As pointed out elsewhere, `touch` won't guarantee the files are empty. If you do use `touch`, you might want to test whether any of the filenames already correspond to (non-empty) files ...

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
touch $(seq 2)
```

or:

```
touch $(seq 2 | sed 's/$/.txt/')
```

if you want a suffix?

Comment: Or  
    touch $(seq 2 | sed 's/$/.txt/'| sed 's/^/empty/') 
to give him the format he was asking for.

Comment: or `touch $(seq 2 | sed 's/.*/empty&.txt/')` to eliminate the extra sed, or even `touch $(seq -f 'empty%.0f.txt' 2)`?  Why use sed at all?

Answer (score 3):

The `touch` command will create a file if it doesn't exist. So you could do:

```
for i in `seq 1 2`; do
    touch empty$i.txt
done
```

If you don't want to use any other commands like `touch`, and do it purely using `bash` commands, you could use the redirection operator `>` without a command in front of it:

```
for i in `seq 1 2`; do
    > empty$i.txt
done
```

For more details see the [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) chapter in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html):

```
> filename    
   # The > truncates file "filename" to zero length.
   # If file not present, creates zero-length file (same effect as 'touch').
   # (Same result as ": >", above, but this does not work with some shells.)
```

Answer (score 2):

The awk command can indeed create empty files on its own, without spawning something in `system()`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ printf("") > "test1" }'
$ ls -l test1
-rw-r--r--  1 ghoti  staff  0 Jan  9 09:58 test1
$
```

Note that each output file is recorded in memory upon use, and that memory is not given back until the output file is closed. You can use the `close()` function to close a file.

```
awk -v n=2 'BEGIN{ for(;n;n--) { f="test"n".txt"; printf("") > f; close(f) } }'
```

But you by no means *need* awk for this, the `touch` works nicely from multiple shells (including bash of course), and the mechanism you use to generate filenames for it are numerous and varied.